# pyHook and pywin32 are installed but not found

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pycharm, pywin32, pyhook

For a project in python I need both the pyHook and pywin32 modules.
I installed them by downloading the .whl files for them and installing them with pip.
But when I try to import them in my project they can not be found.

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 
2018.3.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyHook'
```

For some reason I can import pyHook in IDLE but pywin32 doesn't work in IDLE or pycharm

when I use the command 'pip list' in cmd the two modules are listed.

maybe this could be usefull:

```
os.path
<module 'ntpath' from 
'C:\\Users\\dellSebastiaan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37- 
32\\lib\\ntpath.py'>


for p in sys.path:
print(p)

C:\Users\dellSebastiaan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\idlelib
C:\Users\dellSebastiaan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python37.zip
C:\Users\dellSebastiaan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs
C:\Users\dellSebastiaan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib
C:\Users\dellSebastiaan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32
C:\Users\dellSebastiaan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages
C:\Users\dellSebastiaan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\win32
C:\Users\dellSebastiaan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\win32\lib
C:\Users\dellSebastiaan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\Pythonwin
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please check that interpreter in `File - Settings - Project Interpreter` is specified correctly

Answer (score 1):

If you have not tried, you should uninstall and reinstall the modules with `pip uninstall` and `pip install`. Also, you might want to try `pip3`.

Also, check your `python` version. Your modules may not work if you use `3.7`. Try to do this with `3.6`.